# Adjust the height of a column dynamically

Tags: javascript

This is the page I am working on http://bigislandnaturetours.com/tour/

The issue is I am trying to extend the height of the right column to automatically adjust the height of the left column. I use the following JS  below which I have tested and works on other sites but not on this one. What might be wrong?

```
function doResize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 981) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".leftpane").css("height", "auto");
            $(".midpanel").css("height", "auto");
            var heightLeft = $(".rightpane").height();
            var heightMiddle = $(".midpanel").height();
            var heightRight = $(".leftpane").height();

            if (heightRight > heightMiddle) {

                $('.midpanel').css('min-height', heightRight + 2)

            } else {

                $('.leftpane').css('min-height', heightMiddle + 2)
            }

            heightMiddle = $(".midpanel").height();
            heightRight = $(".leftpane").height();

            if (heightLeft >= heightRight) {
                $(".leftpane").css("height", heightLeft - 10);
                $(".midpanel").css("height", heightLeft - 10);
            }

        }, 1000);
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    doResize();
});


$(window).resize(function() {
    doResize();
    if ($(window).width() < 561) {
        $(".leftpane").css("min-height", "auto");
        $(".midpanel").css("min-height", "auto");
    }
    $('.main-nav li').unbind("click");
    if ($('.rightpane').css('display') == 'none') {
        $('.main-nav li').bind("click", function() {
            $(this).addClass('im-curent');
            $("ul", this).toggle(100);
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to use flex-box CSS (HTML5 / CSS3) or, for older browsers, a table used in 'presentation' mode.

Both should automatically keep column height in sync.